# rally set default value for combo box

Tags: combobox, filter, rally, default-value

I have a combobox for State that successfully filters in Rally.  The code below works. I want to add an enhancement and have the combobox default to 'In Progress'.  I added defaultValue but it has no effect. Thanks for your help.

```
    Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('Rally.example.CustomStoreGrid', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',

            launch: function() {
                Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                    model: 'defect',
                    autoLoad: true,
                    limit: 1000,
                    pageSize: 1000,
                    listeners: {
                        load: this._onDataLoaded,
                        scope: this
                    },
                    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Severity', 'State', 'InProgressDate', 'c_PlannedDeliveryVersion']
                });
            },
            _onSelect: function() {
              var grid = this.down('rallygrid'), store = grid.getStore();
              store.clearFilter(true);

              store.filter(this._getStateFilter());
            },  
            _getStateFilter: function() {
                return {
                    property: 'State',
                    operator: '=',
                    defaultValue: 'In Progress',

                    value: this.down('#priorityComboBox').getValue()

                };
            },
            _onDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
                var records = _.map(data, function(record) {
                    //Perform custom actions with the data here
                    //Calculations, etc.
                    return Ext.apply({
                       // Age: Math.round(((new Date() - record.get('InProgressDate')) / 86400000) * 10) / 10;
                    }, record.getData());
                });
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
                    itemId: 'priorityComboBox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Filter by State:',
                    model: 'defect',

                  //  multiSelect: true,
                    field: 'State',

                    listeners: {
                        select: this._onSelect,
                      //  ready: this._onLoad,
                        scope: this
                    }
                });
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    showPagingToolbar: false,
                    showRowActionsColumn: false,
                    editable: false,
                    store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                       limit: 1000,
                       pageSize: 1000,
                       data: records
                    }),
                    columnCfgs: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                            text: 'ID',
                            dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                            width: 100,
                            tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Name',
                            dataIndex: 'Name',
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Severity',
                            dataIndex: 'Severity'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'State',
                            dataIndex: 'State'

                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Planned Delivery Version',
                            dataIndex: 'c_PlannedDeliveryVersion',
                            flex: 0.25
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'In Progress Date',
                            dataIndex: 'InProgressDate',
                            xtype: 'datecolumn',   
                            format:'Y-m-d'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Age',
                            dataIndex: 'InProgressDate'
                            ,
                            renderer: function(value) {
                                return Math.round(((new Date() - value) / 86400000) * 10) / 10;
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });


        Rally.launchApp('Rally.example.CustomStoreGrid', {
          name: 'Custom Store Grid Example'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `value` config property sets the default value:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    items:{ html:'<a href="https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/">App SDK 2.0rc3 Docs</a>'},
    launch: function() {
        this.add({
                xtype: 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
                model: 'UserStory',
                field: 'ScheduleState',
                value: 'In-Progress'
            });
    }
});
```